# How to pass parameter to running application

Tags: java

it's even possible to somehow pass parameter (and do stuff with it) to running application like

> my_application.exe param1

without starting new instance of it?

Update:

I using custom uri like "smt://" and then people press on link like "smt:m=21345345" i need to pass it to program. If my program not running it should start it, if its running it should just pass parameter to it without starting new instance.

Comment: Not from the command line, no.

Comment: You can get information from the command line via the standard input, System.in.

Comment: Maybe. You could open a socket and listen in your application for commands. Then you can connect to the instance and pass in a "parameter" command.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: you're probably right. His question is a bit sparse on detail, and so all I can do is comment and not answer yet til either he improves his question or I get better at guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Would you really want to change the parameter at a time when the application is not expecting it?  The application should check for new inputs at appropriate moments.